# Unable to save line break and < mark in MariaDB / MySQL

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am unable to save following string entered in `textarea` from the browser.

```
a
<br>b
```

MariaDB / Apache server becomes unresponsive when above string passed from the client.

This is client side JavaScript

```
// ...
var description = document.getElementById("txt_manage_remind_desc").value.trim();
// ...
// ...
$.get("PHP/MyAjax.php?page=addNewRemind&remindId="+remindId+"&remindText="+remindText+"&description="+description+"&isEvent="+timeEventIsOn+"&eventTime="+eventTime+"&public_or_private="+public_or_private+"&moveToAfter="+moveToAfter, function(responseText) {
 // responseText Usage
}
```

This is server side PHP

```
// ...
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_REQUEST['description']);
// ...
// ...
// Insertion of New Remind
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO  `reminders` (
                          `user_id` ,
                          `reminder` ,
                          `description` ,
                          `is_an_event` ,
                          `event_time` ,
                          `public_or_private` ,
                          `created_on` ,
                          `type` ,
                          `priority`
                          )
                          VALUES (
                          ?,
                          ?,
                          ?,
                          ?,
                          ?,
                          ?,
                          NOW(),
                          'user_defined',
                          ?
                          )");
if(false === $stmt) {
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
}
$rc = $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $session_id, $remindText, $description, $isEvent, $eventTime, $public_or_private, $newPriority);
if(false === $rc) {
  die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
$rc = $stmt->execute();
if(false === $rc) {
  die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
else {
  echo "saved";
}
```

I was using `escape()` function from JavaScript to escape problematic characters which was saving records but converting special characters to unwanted symbols.
I discovered that the problem is due to combination of `line break` and `<`.
Suggest any JavaScript or PHP solution to solve this issue.

Comment: Use POST to send data to the server and GET to fetch data from the server. When you send data in the query string, you need to [uri-encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the data, but as mentioned, you should really use POST here. Then there's no need to encode anything in neither JS or PHP.

Comment: You should also remove all the `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. When you're using prepared statements with placeholders (which you are), you shouldn't escape the data at all. Just save it "as is".

Comment: Also, isn't `$session_id` an integer? Then you should have `i` instead of `s` for the first value `->bind_param("issssss", ...)`.

Comment: A simple `htmlentities()` should let you save description in a proper way. It should look something like`&lt;br&gt;...`. Also, why `htmlspecialchars()` on `$mysqli->error`?

Comment: @vivek_23 Your comment makes no sense. Don't use htmlentities on the data going into the database. And you should use htmlentities or htmlspecialchars on every output to HTML, even on error messages.

Comment: @Dharman But why would you want to store plain HTML as is? It could contain malicious script tags. Also, why htmlentities() on error messages? They are generated by PHP. Of course you would need this if data is stored as is.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson there is no rule saying you *should* use i for integers.

Comment: may be it's some protections from your host/whatever. There is no evidence the issue is mysqli related, so the tag is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using GET method. GET method follow the URL rule. Not accepting certain characters.

Heresome solution.

1. Use POST

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("description", document.getElementById("txt_manage_remind_desc").value.trim());
fd.append("remindId", remindId);
//add more fd.append() like you put GET

var x = new XMHttpRequest();
x.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(this.status == 200 && this.readystate == 4){
       console.log("success sent");
   }
}
x.open("POST", "PHP/MyAjax.php?page=addNewRemind", true);
x.send(fd);
```

Then in you PHP codes, the `$_GET` method, change to `$_POST` method.

```
$description = $_POST["description"];
//add more others key=value
```

2. Other way, you can Encode you data in Base64

```
// ...
var description = document.getElementById("txt_manage_remind_desc").value.trim();
// ...
// ...
$.get("PHP/MyAjax.php?page=addNewRemind&remindId="+remindId+"&remindText="+remindText+"&description="+ btoa(description) +"&isEvent="+timeEventIsOn+"&eventTime="+eventTime+"&public_or_private="+public_or_private+"&moveToAfter="+moveToAfter, function(responseText) {
 // responseText Usage
}
```

Some time in JS default `atob()` and `btoa()` function not working because it's not represent 8-bit byte char. So you need another JS base64 function.

```
    function base64_encode(str) {
        return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
            function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
                return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
        }));
    }
    function base64_decode(str) {
        return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
            return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join(''));
    }
```

So if you use the new function, then you query will be:

```
// ...
var description = document.getElementById("txt_manage_remind_desc").value.trim();
// ...
// ...
$.get("PHP/MyAjax.php?page=addNewRemind&remindId="+remindId+"&remindText="+remindText+"&description="+ base64_encode(description) +"&isEvent="+timeEventIsOn+"&eventTime="+eventTime+"&public_or_private="+public_or_private+"&moveToAfter="+moveToAfter, function(responseText) {
 // responseText Usage
}
```

Then, in your PHP, you will need to decode it to string just like `$description = base64_decode($description);`